# Regex expression not returning entire term

Tags: javascript, regex, string, escaping, match

The intention of the regex is to capture substrings wrapped between twin expressions in parentheses, kinda like html tags. For example:

```html
<p id="textTwo">And this shall be (blue)the ocean(blue) and this shall also be like (blue)the ocean(blue)</p>
```

And here's my code

```js
let color = 'blue';
let getColor = 
    new RegExp(`(${color})(.*)(${color})`);
let coloredText = textTwo.match(getColor);
```

```js
let text = document.getElementById('text').innerText;
let textTwo = document.getElementById('text2').innerText;

let color = 'blue';
let getColor = 
    new RegExp(`(${color})(.*)(${color})`);
let coloredText = textTwo.match(getColor);
// italicsText.forEach((string, index) => {
//   string.replace("(i)", "<i>");
//   console.log(typeof(string));
// });
// text.replace(italics, "<i>");

let italics = text.replace(/\((.*?)\)/g, (_, match) => `<${match}>`);
console.log(italics);


console.log(italics);
console.log(coloredText);
```

```html
<p id="text">Hello there (i)Good Sir(i). How can I help you (i)today(i)</p>

<p id="text2">And this shall be (blue)ao!(blue) and this shall also be (blue)like the ocean(blue)</p>
```

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't capture the entire thing?

Comment: What do you expect `coloredText` to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters `()` are special in a regexp and must be escaped with a `\` if you want to match them literally. And because `\` in a JavaScript string literal is also special, it needs to be escaped with another `\`:

```
    let color = 'blue';
    let getColor = 
        new RegExp(`\\(${color}\\)(.*)\\(${color}\\)`);
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex for the `'(blue)'` specific case would be ... [`/\(blue\)(?<colored>.*?)\(blue\)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/eHCaWJ/1).

The above regex literal does (needs to) escape regex specific characters like `(` and `)` for they have special meaning like for the latter two marking a capturing group.

In order to dynamically match/capture color value related patterns one needs to utilize

- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- and the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp) constructor.

In comparison to the regex literal one does provide a string based `pattern` parameter to the `RegExp` constructor where one needs to escape the pattern's escape characters (`\` to `'\\'`).

```js
const sampleText =
 'And this shall be (blue)the ocean(blue) and this shall also be like (blue)another ocean(blue)';

const sampleColor = 'blue';

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/eHCaWJ/1]
// ... /\(blue\)(?<colored>.*?)\(blue\)/g

const regExpColored =
  RegExp(`\\(${ sampleColor }\\)(?<colored>.*?)\\(${ sampleColor }\\)`, 'g');

console.log(
  'all matches ...',
  sampleText
    .match(regExpColored)
)
console.log(
  'any capture ...',
  Array
    .from(
      sampleText
        .matchAll(regExpColored)
    )
    .map(({ groups: { colored }}) => colored)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```